# What do you call the upper part of a robe?

Tags: word-usage

[image]

I thought the word was bosom, but I heard bosom is never used in the context of a robe, it's used when we're referring to the upper part of a dress shirt.

It seems that the bosom refers to the white protruding part of a dress shirt, although I am not sure if this is exact and what part of it exactly, the whole part of the white thing or just the flat portion?
[image]

Comment: You are probably looking for décolleté:  https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.collinsdictionary.com/it/amp/inglese/decollete

Comment: I thought that décolleté was a description of the whole dress - one that had a low top - rather than the top part of a dress itself.

Comment: The upper part of a dress or ball gown (I wouldn't call the garment in the photo a robe) is the **bodice**

Comment: Your first example is a wedding *dress* or bridal *gown*. Are these garments commonly called *robes*, as you have it in your question’s title? Also, it would help for you to describe what you meant by “upper part” so that you can exclude answers such as “collar”.

Comment: Yeah, that’s a dress. And the upper part is missing!  :-)

Comment: @Greybeard - (on a piece of women's clothing) a bodice that has a very low neckline.

Comment: The **décolletage** is the low neckline. And sometimes it is the section that is *not* part of the dress, i.e. the wearer's bust.

Comment: *above the sash* - but first you need a picture of a robe.

Comment: That is not a robe. It is a dress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I googled "parts of a dress".

[SOURCE](https://www.ivyandpearlboutique.com/fashion-and-news/fashion-school/illustrated-guide-dress-styles-types-silhouettes/)

[image]

Then I did "parts of a shirt" bosom

[SOURCE](https://journal.styleforum.net/the-anatomy-of-a-formal-shirt/)

[image]

Comment: Bodice doesn't imply a low neckline, décolleté does. https://www.collinsdictionary.com/it/dizionario/inglese/decollete

Comment: _Bosom_ is a rather old-fashioned word. According to GEdgar's illustration, it is still used for the stiff front of a dress shirt (itself a style that has survived from the 19th century), but  in ordinary conversation we would speak of the _front_ of a shirt or blouse.